# Javascript not showing .value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, telerik

I am trying to use JavaScript to set a textbox text equal to "" or NULL. I am using visual studio 2013 and have created an asp.net web application. I am also using telerik controls(not sure if that will affect anything). I currently have a combobox(ddlMaritalStatus) and a textbox(txtSpouseName). I currently have JavaScript that when ddlMaritalStatus selected text is set to single then txtSpouseName is disabled. I would also like to have txtSpouseName have its text erased when ddlMaritalStatus is changed back to single. I have been researching through Google and through stack overflow and have not come across an option that works. Every answer I have found says to use `document.getElementById("txtSpouseName").value = "";` but my program is not reading the .value with JavaScript.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlMaritalStatus" runat="server" EmptyMessage="--Select--" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="DisableBox" TabIndex="15" AutoPostBack="false"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function DisableBox() {
                        var TextBox = $find("<%=txtSpouseName.ClientID %>");
                        var Location = $find("<%=ddlMaritalStatus.ClientID %>");
                                if (Location.get_text().length < 7) {
                                    TextBox.disable();
                                    document.getElementById("txtSpouseName").value = "";
                                }
                                else {
                                    TextBox.enable();
                                }
                            }
                </script>

<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSpouseName" runat="server" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="false" TabIndex="16"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Here is the code that I have so far. Any help or suggestions would be great! Thanks!

**EDIT**
I am using IE 11.

Comment: Do you have any client side errors in your browser `Console`? e.g. `$` - `$find` vs `$.find` (jquery vs what i think ms ajax)?

Comment: @EdSF It did not like when I switched from '$find to $.find' Is that what you wanted me to check?

Comment: Not exactly (just checking what/which lib you're using). What do you use to check for client side errors - re: to find out if there is a Javascript error in your page? For example Chrome (`CTRL+SHIFT+I`) or IE (`F12`) dev tools -> Console (this will display Javascript errors that will should help). Also, you're using `ClientID` vs. `"txtSpouseName"` (hard-coding it)...

Comment: @EdSF Okay I am using IE. I hit F12 and went to console. I did have any errors and no warnings or messages related to javascript. When I try to select a value from ddlMaritalStatus an error does come up saying **0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_text'** Does this help at all? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I found from another post. This disables the textbox when "Married" is selected and erases and disable the textbox when "Single" is selected. Thank you to everyone who tried to help me!

function DisableBox(sender, args) {

```
var TextBox = $find("<%=txtSpouseName.ClientID %>");

if (args.get_item().get_text() == "Married") {

    TextBox.enable();

}

else {

    TextBox.clear();

    TextBox.disable();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
        if (sender.get_selectedItem().get_value() == "Single") {
            document.getElementById(sender.get_id().replace("ddlMaritalStatus", "txtSpouseName")).value = "";
            document.getElementById(sender.get_id().replace("ddlMaritalStatus", "txtSpouseName")).disabled = "disabled";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(sender.get_id().replace("ddlMaritalStatus", "txtSpouseName")).value = "";
            document.getElementById(sender.get_id().replace("ddlMaritalStatus", "txtSpouseName")).disabled = "";
        }
    }

</script>
...........
...........
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlMaritalStatus" runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="ClientSelectedIndexChanged">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="Married" Text="Married" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="Single" Text="Single" />
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpouseName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The text is working great now but the disable is not. I need txtSpouseName to be disabled unless "Married" is selected. I put your code into my project and it allows txtSpouseName to be enabled all the time. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide your browser and textbox detail?

Comment: I add the information to the original post. If you need more information let me know! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I found my original code for disabling the text box here [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/javascript-to-disable-textbox-when-radcombox-is-selected)  but now when I try and combine the two I get an error saying " JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'enabled' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: Your code is working correctly. Let me know once you availabe we will discuss this issue in stackoverflow chat.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out Jayesh. I unfortunately did not see this comment until this morning. I found the answer to my problem on another forum and the code works great. Thanks for trying to help me out!